# How do you update a URL in angular 13+ but not trigger navigation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic6

We have an library.page.html. On the left side of the HTMl there is a list, where you can select a book. When the page renders there is just this list, and when I select a book I want to update the URL to /books/123, but don't trigger the navigation itself. On the page itself there is some code on the right side that renders on *ngIf=bookselected | async.

As expected using angulars router navigate it tries to match to a path, and navigates to it.
We want to do this so when you copy the link and send it to another person, that it will load the books page with book 123 loaded in the detail pane.

Our page consists of 1 outlet (ionic). I can solve it by using params on the page itself (url will turn into books?id=123) and when I navigate to the page I can use this.router.navigate(['books', 123]).

I remember from the old Angular days you could just customize the url via the navController, but this seems frowned upon (since the URL does "more" than just navigate" now for angular).

Is adjusting the url with "paths" frowned upon, and should I use queryParams on the page itself? Or am I missing something in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location: Location) {}

changeUrl(path: string): void {
  this.location.go(path);
}
```